# Subadditivity for Analytic Capacity Disjoint Compacts separated by a Line

Tags: complex-analysis

The following problem is asked in Greene and Krantz, Problem 9, page 382:

> Suppose that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjoint compact sets in $\mathbb{C}$ that can be separated by a line $l$ with $C_1 \cap l = C_2 \cap l = \emptyset$. Show that
>   $$\gamma(C_1 \cup C_2) \leq \gamma(C_1) + \gamma(C_2).$$

Here, $\gamma(C)$ is the [analytic capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_capacity) of the compact set $C\subset \mathbb{C}$.

All my ideas to solve this problem reach a dead end pretty quickly. Two ideas initially felt right. One was Schwarz reflection. The other was finding an open disk containing $C_1$ but that is disjoint with $C_2$, then use the Cauchy integral formula on this disk to help define a function that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash C_2$ that has norm $\leq$ 1. I don't think either of these ideas are useful.

Comment: What does it mean $\gamma(C)$?

Comment: That is the analytic capacity of C.

Comment: I would be very interested in seeing a proof of this. I have no idea how to prove something like that. My Ph.D. thesis was on analytic capacity, and I've never seen or heard of a similar result. If I had to guess, I would say that it is still open, but who knows... Maybe one should contact Greene or Krantz?

Comment: @MalikYounsi I e-mailed Greene a couple of days ago, but no answer up to this moment...

Comment: @JoãoRamos Did you get a reply eventually?