# $\epsilon - \delta$ Definition of Derivative at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

I was thinking of a $\epsilon - \delta$ Definition of Derivative at infinity (which we can take according to [Can you take the derivative of a function at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747593/can-you-take-the-derivative-of-a-function-at-infinity)) of a real valued function.

I tried making one one the lines of limit, where limit at a finite point $c \in A$ of $f: A \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $ is said to be $L$ if
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 (\exists \delta(\epsilon) > 0) \text{  such that } |x - c| <\delta(\epsilon) \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon
$$
My textbook (Bartle-Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis (4th Edition)*) extends definition for limit at infinity as follow: A function $f: (a,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $ is said to have limit $L$ as $ x \rightarrow  \infty$ if
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 (\exists M(\epsilon) > a )\text{  such that } x >M(\epsilon) \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon
$$
I tried doing the same for derivatives, but the problem I am facing is that definition of derivatives contain this term:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - L \right| < \epsilon
$$
Where $c$ is the point where we wish to calculate, so even if I consider x above a certain values (say $x >M(\epsilon) $ I am still left with $c$.

Comment: Infinity is not a number. The best you might do is take the derivative at x then take the limit of this expression as x tends to infinity.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747593/can-you-take-the-derivative-of-a-function-at-infinity